# Can you point DNS records for a domain name at a site on AppHarbor with the free account?

Tags: appharbor

Just like the question says. I have deployed a site to AppHarbor, and then I updated the DNS A record for a domain name to point at the IP given on the 'Hostnames' page. The DNS hasn't updated properly yet so can't see if it's worked.

Has anyone else done this and had it work?

Comment: app harbor is a .NET deployment/hosting service, the c# tag gets it seen by all the people who are browsing the c# questions, and who are also most likely the people who have experience of app harbor, so that is "where comes c#"

Comment: @dormisher, my closure vote was to migrate to webmasters.stackexchange.com, but not enough of the other close votes were for that =( Your question isn't really a "coding" question so it's certainly worth a try re-posting your question there (after checking out their FAQ) to get the answer you're after =) That said, DNS can just be very slow so it might be worth waiting it out and letting DNS propogate to see what happens =)

Answer (score 2):

It will work with a free account until the 1st of March (although I am not sure if you can add them now). Then you will have to have payment information as it will cost $10 a month.

Another option is to somehow forward the web request to the *.apphb.com address.

I have some free (Canoe) applications there and the DNS worked fine for the hostnames. Although I am not at the point to really need them enough to pay for them, so I removed them and haven't tried re-adding a hostname to see if it will require payment information.

(Information coming from here: http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/02/02/announcing-pricing)